# Postfix emails error, loops back to myself

Tags: postfix, lamp

I'm struggling with Postfix to send out emails from a form on my website:

Google Domain, hosting provided by DigitalOcean with a LAMP droplet; this is my DNS config:

[image: dns config]

Mail function on my .php file wants to send an email
from: `info@mydomain.io`
to: `myname@mydomain.io`

all goes succesfully except emails are not actually sent.

`/var/log/mail.log` mentions that `status=bounced (mail for mydomain.io loops back to myself)`

Here's my `main.cf` config:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = packer-611a9b0e-18c5-2e19-5583-bed9efc126b7
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
myorigin = /etc/mailname
```

I looked every guide available to tweak `/etc/postfix/main.cf` but nothing works, thanks in advance to anybody who's willing to help.

Comment: You need to list your domain in `mydestination`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have `MX` `DNS` records defined, the mail to `mydomain.io` will be delivered to an `IP` from `A` `DNS` record for `mydomain.io`, which (as I can guess) is the same as your web application. As your application is attempting to send an email to `mydomain.io` through `postfix` it loops back to itself. You need to configure your `postfix` to accept email for `mydomain.io` by setting `mydestination` or point `MX` records to a server that handles email for domain `mydomain.io`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexD, any suggestion on how to do so please? I'm struggling to get if this has to be taken care of by the google domain on which the domain (and email domain) is registered or by the hosting platform.